# Problem with ikfast_moveit tutorial

Tags: ros, rviz, motoman, moveit-tutorial, ikfast

[image: Rosanswers logo]

link: http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Kinematics/IKFast

when I finish the tutorial, I try to run: "roslaunch motoman_mh5_moveit_config demo.launch"
The rviz opens correctly, but then it closes and the terminal shows:

```
All is well! Everyone is happy! You can start planning now!

[ INFO] [1397151951.649167498]: Loading robot model 'motoman_mh5'...
[ INFO] [1397151951.649462158]: No root joint specified. Assuming fixed joint
[ INFO] [1397151952.044567779]: joint_s -2.9671 2.9671 1
[ INFO] [1397151952.044887373]: joint_l -1.1345 2.618 1
[ INFO] [1397151952.045032293]: joint_u -2.3736 4.4506 1
[ INFO] [1397151952.045166528]: joint_r -3.3161 3.3161 1
[ INFO] [1397151952.045301182]: joint_b -2.1817 2.1817 1
[ INFO] [1397151952.045439119]: joint_t -6.2831 6.2831 1
[ INFO] [1397151952.225434215]: Starting scene monitor
[ INFO] [1397151952.227811123]: Listening to '/move_group/monitored_planning_scene'
[ INFO] [1397151952.732558619]: No active joints or end effectors found for group ''. Make sure you have defined an end effector in your SRDF file and that kinematics.yaml is loaded in this node's namespace.

[name_machine_15204_2001356156261009935-4] process has died [pid 15262, exit code -11, cmd /opt/ros/hydro/lib/rviz/rviz -d ~/catkin_workspace/src/motoman_mh5_moveit_config/launch/moveit.rviz __name:=rviz_machine_15204_2001356156261009935 __log:=~/.ros/log/e8dfae26-c0d5-11e3-9580-00216a36b28c/rviz_ismael_ThinkPad_T500_15204_2001356156261009935-4.log].
log file: ~/.ros/log/e8dfae26-c0d5-11e3-9580-00216a36b28c/rviz_machine_15204_2001356156261009935-4*.log
```

---

Update:

`kinematics.yaml`:

```
planning_group:
    kinematics_solver: motoman_mh5_planning_group_kinematics/IKFastKinematicsPlugin
    kinematics_solver_attempts: 3
    kinematics_solver_search_resolution: 0.005
    kinematics_solver_timeout: 0.005
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/151656/problem-with-ikfast_moveit-tutorial/) by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2014-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-04-11**:
RViz seems to be crashing with a `SIGSEGV` (segmentation fault: -11), which can be caused by trying to access an invalid pointer fi. Is this with the IKFast plugin configured in the kinematics.yaml file?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-04-14**:
It would seem you created the MH5 IKFast plugin yourself (AFAIK ROS-Industrial does not supply an MH5 setup). It would help if you could make your pkg / code available somewhere.

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-04-16**:
Which file do you need?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-04-16**:
All of the pkgs that you created yourself, relating to the MH5 (so the MoveIt configuration pkg and the IKFast plugin package).

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-04-16**:
Also, have you checked those logfiles? There could be something in there which could help in debugging this issue (graphics card driver failure, etc).

**Comment by [Bastbeat](https://answers.ros.org/users/12796/bastbeat/) on 2014-04-16**:
Here, I have Upload my files: https://github.com/Bastbeat/ikfastproblem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After taking a look at your MoveIt configuration package, it appears you have defined a planning group by selecting the *Add Joints* option. From your `motoman_mh5.srdf` file:

```
<group name="planning_group">
    <link name="base_link" />
    <link name="link_b" />
    ...
    <joint name="joint_s" />
    <joint name="joint_l" />
    ...
</group>
```

I'm not sure why (yet), but MoveIt (or RViz) doesn't seem to like that (see also [ros-industrial/universal_robot#41](https://github.com/ros-industrial/universal_robot/issues/41)).

If you instead define your planning group as a *kinematic chain*, things should work just fine. You can do this using the MoveIt Setup Assistant, or just editing your `srdf` directly. Something like the following should do:

```
<group name="planning_group">
    <chain base_link="base_link" tip_link="link_t" />
</group>
```

BTW: your MoveIt configuration package was missing quite a few launch files (`demo.launch` and `move_group.launch` among others). Make sure it is complete.

---

You also might want to rename your planning group to `manipulator`, which is the ROS-Industrial standard name for a planning group (see also the [Create a MoveIt Package for an Industrial Robot](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_MoveIt_Pkg_for_an_Industrial_Robot) tutorial).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-04-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2